# intellij idea failed to generate flex compiler configuration file

Tags: apache-flex, maven, intellij-idea

I'm experiencing an issue developing in intellij idea.

Here is the situation: We have maven nested project with java+js(extjs)+html+ActionScript source code in it. The thing is, that evey time I introduce any changes to ANY pom.xml in my project intellij idea tries to generate some configuration file for flex compiler. Some time it succeed to do this and some time not. Independent on that, this task eats to many resources so intellij idea starts lagging.

Is there any way how this config file generating can be turned off?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable auto import of Maven projects via Settings -> Maven -> Importing. Then uncheck "Import Maven projects automatically".

Note that AFAIK it is not possible to ignore the generation of Flex config files while this option is on.

Comment: There's 'Generate Flex compiler config files' check box at the bottom of this settings page.

Comment: Yes, but if you disable this, then the Flex config will never be generated, not even when initially importing the project?

Comment: @AlexanderDoroshko, could you, please, add this to your answer so I can accept it? That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Settings | Maven | Importing | Import Maven projects automatically.